# Problem creating Singleton class in iOS Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I am trying to create singleton class in Objective-C. following is .h and .m file.

**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"

@interface LGHTTPRequest : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

-(instancetype)sharedHTTPRequest;

-(void)postWithUrl:(NSString*)url parameter:(NSDictionary*)parameters;
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "LGHTTPRequest.h"

static NSString* BaseURLString = @"someurl";

@implementation LGHTTPRequest

-(instancetype)sharedHTTPRequest
{
    static LGHTTPRequest *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[LGHTTPRequest alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString]];

        _sharedClient.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        [_sharedClient.securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
        _sharedClient.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/x-json"];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}


-(void)postWithUrl:(NSString *)url parameter:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    //implemented but no need to show here
}

@end
```

Problem is, I can create instance using `sharedHTTPRequest`, but at same time I can call alloc/init. Then how to ensure, my class is singleton?

Comment: Don't use alloc init, only use the shared instance class method. It's that simple.

Comment: BTW, a method that returns a singleton is typically a _class method_ declared with a `+` instead of an _instance method_ declared with a `-`.

Comment: @user3386109 Good catch, I missed that. That's definitely the problem.

Comment: @user3386109 Oh, I fixed that, but still I can access alloc/init

Comment: @CrimsonChris So, I cannot restrict alloc/init to use out of the class?

Comment: @pranitkothari It is restricted by convention, there isn't anything you can do in objective-c to stop somebody from calling a method. Don't try to stop them. Use comments to communicate what you _should_ do if it's not already clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the user to call the `init` method then you can make the `init` of that class unavailable by writing following code. So it will make sure that the `init` method will not be called on that class.

```
 /*!
@method init

@abstract Should create only one instance of class. Should not call init.
```

`*/`

`- (id)init __attribute__((unavailable("init is not available in yourClassName, Use sharedManager"));`

```
/*!
@method new

@abstract Should create only one instance of class. Should not call new.
```

`*/`

`+ (id)new  __attribute__((unavailable("new is not available in yourClassName, Use sharedManager"));`

Comment: This is about as close as you can get to stopping somebody from calling a method in objective-c. If somebody really wanted to call it they still could by using `performSelector`. In objective-c, almost everything is enforced "by convention".